# Display HTML content into rows vertically

Tags: html, css

I have an html file with one main div

```
<body><div id="main">.....</div></body
```

I want to divide html content into rows with same height and some padding between them.
It will look like as if I copied manually content into a table with several rows ,with borders on each row, and divided content equally into it.

Is there any css to do this?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle and your html css code please?

Comment: It's a common problem. Have you at least searched for some solution or tried anything? There are several ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a table

```
<div id="main">
<table>
    <tr class="DataRow"><p>Content</p></tr>
    <tr class="DataRow"><p>Content2</p></tr>
    <tr class="DataRow"><p>Content3</p></tr>
    <tr class="DataRow"><p>Content4</p></tr>
    <tr class="DataRow"><p>Content5</p></tr>
</table>
```

css

```
.DataRow{
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: I don't have control over what is inside my main division.I cant divide them manually since I have many html files. So I don't really know how many rows each html file will be divided into. I do want the behavior of a table but I don't want to do it manually. It need something in css , like multi-column layout but in the opposite direction. Multi column layout divides html into columns horizontally with gap between them, I want to do the same but vertically if possible

Answer (score 0):

off the top of my head, maybe below might point you in the right direction? just a border and some padding?
By default div tags are block elements, meaning that they reside on a new line anyway (this can be changes via css)

to divide the content, you would need to use javascript

str.length() and divide this value by 2 into an array, and place [0] into div 1 and [1] into div 2

jquery:-

```
$("#row1").text([0]) 
$("#row2").text([1])
```

CSS-

```
<style type="text/css">
.row { border:solid 1px #000; padding:5px }
</style>

<div id="main">
   <div id="row1" class="row">Content row 1</div>
   <div id="row2" class="row">Content row 2</div>
</div>
```